# How to access session in MVC 1.0

Tags: model-view-controller, session, reference

In an MVC 1.0 C# app, what's the different between the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] = "ItsValue";
```

and

```
Session["MyValue"] = "ItsValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

`Session["MyValue"]` is accessing a property of the ViewPage object. I you're trying to get to the session from another class which isn't a ViewPage, you'd use `HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];`

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent in that they reference the same object.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session == this.Session
```